# Create new order status and make it visible on frontend

Tags: magento2, order-status

I have created a new order status and assign it to processing state:

UpgradeSchema.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup(); 

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.1", "<")) {
          $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
          $status = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status');
          $status->setData('status', 'delivery_pending')->setData('label', 'Delivery Pending')->save();
          $status->assignState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING, true);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

The problem is when the order of my new order status won't show at frontend and when I check at admin page in order status configuration, the new order status is not visible on storefront

[image: example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you need to replace this statement with following.

> $status->assignState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING,
>   true);

Replace with

> $status->assignState(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING,
>   true, true);

Even you can try the alternative for setup script.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{

    public function upgrade(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup(); 

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), "1.0.1", "<")) {
          $data[] = ['status' => 'delivery_pending', 'label' => 'Delivery Pending'];
          $setup->getConnection()->insertArray($setup->getTable('sales_order_status'), ['status', 'label'], $data);
          $setup->getConnection()->insertArray(
            $setup->getTable('sales_order_status_state'),
            ['status', 'state', 'is_default','visible_on_front'],
            ['delivery_pending','processing','0',1]
         );
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```